# If ruby encourages duck typing so much, why don't we have Hash.count instead of Hash.length?

Tags: ruby, oop, duck-typing

This is something that really confuses me, it seems like time and time again I run into methods in ruby native data types that do the same thing (essentially), and yet have different names.  If duck typing is so strongly encouraged by ruby and the ruby community, why aren't these methods named consistently across types?

Answer (score 11):

You seem to imply that Hash does not have a `length` method and/or that other enumerables don't have a `count` method. That is not true.

`count` is a method defined in the `Enumerable` module and thus available on all enumerables. It differs from `size` and `length` in the following ways:

1. It (optionally) takes a block specifying which kind of elements to count.
2. It's available on all enumerables - not just those that keep track of their size - however it has a runtime in `O(n)` for those that don't (and always when given a block of course).

`length` and `size` (which are synonyms) are methods defined on all enumerable classes that keep track of their size (including `Hash`). They differ from count in that they always return the length in `O(1)` time and don't take a block.

In summary: You can call `length` or `size` on any object that keeps track of its size and you can call `count` on any enumerable. So duck typing is not hampered in any way.

Comment: Do you have a citation that `count` is `O(n)` in hashes when no block is supplied, or are you assuming it isn't optimized?

Comment: @Andrew: I don't have a citation, but I'm not just assuming either. I did `{}.method(:count)` in irb and it displayed as `Hash(Enumerable)#count`, which means that `Hash` does not override `count`. And `Enumerable#count` definitely is `O(n)`.

Comment: From [RDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001483): "Returns the number of items in enum, where `size` is called if it responds to it ...". Duck typing FTW!

Comment: @Andrew: Ah, damn. Didn't think of that possibility. Anyway I've that bit in my answer now, thanks.